# Calling javascript in a php page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to call this JS function inside a php page (footer.php), but it's not working. I've tried multiple options, like placing the script inside a php echo, but that didn't work either. I'm stuck here. Any suggestions to call it properly?

```
<?php
/**
* Header for our theme
*/

electro_get_footer();
?>    
<div class="kiyoh">
<span id="cijfer" class="review-cijfer"></span>
<span class="review-cijfer-after"> / 10</span>
<a href="https://kiyoh.nl/lumenlab">
<span id="beoordelingen" class="review-beoordelingen"></span>
<span class="review-beoordelingen-after"> beoordelingen</span>
</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", 
"https://www.kiyoh.nl/xml/recent_company_reviews.xml? connectorcode=xws9TE3TQSX7t7Hrj9xFAbYwhraBaenGFHYWt9jKyx4CRV5vFW&company 
_id=16907&reviewcount=all&showextraquestions=1", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
document.getElementById("cijfer").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("total_score") 
[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("beoordelingen").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("total_reviews") 
[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: add alert inside `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { alert("in")` to see whether your function gets called

Comment: Added the alert, but it didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: that means your function won't get called. try checking your conditions

Answer (score 0):

I have change the url in the xhttp.open() function and it work.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
  } else {
    console.log("readyState: " + this.readyState);
    console.log("Status: " + this.status);
  }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.kiyoh.nl/xml/recent_company_reviews.xml?connectorcode=xws9TE3TQSX7t7Hrj9xFAbYwhraBaenGFHYWt9jKyx4CRV5vFW&company_id=16907&reviewcount=all&showextraquestions=1", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

  document.getElementById("cijfer").innerHTML        = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("total_score") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("beoordelingen").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("total_reviews") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: check the output in the developer console in the myFunction() with console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("total_score") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

Comment: The javascript is working great. I can reproduce your problem... but i can see the request to kiyoh.nl give sometimes a status 404 back.. there is the problem with CORS header. You can find information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: yeah, the url wasn't working. I fixed it by placing a / at the end of the url. Still, the code isn't working :(

Comment: I added a else on the onreadystatechange. Please check the values on your developer console.